# CakePHP Group By field is returning only one result per group

Tags: mysql, cakephp, group-by, find

I have one table as follows:

```
id | date       | customer_id | env_id | jobs
1  | 2012-11-20 | 200         | 100    | 10
2  | 2012-11-20 | 200         | 101    | 15
3  | 2012-11-20 | 200         | 102    | 12
4  | 2012-11-21 | 200         | 100    | 10
5  | 2012-11-21 | 200         | 101    | 12
6  | 2012-11-21 | 200         | 102    | 20
```

What I'm after is the results grouped by date.

```
$usage = $this->Environment->DailyCount->find('all',
array(
'conditions' =>array('DailyCount.customer_id' => $user['customer_id']),
'group' => array('DailyCount.date'),
'recursive'=>-1));
```

but it is only returning one row I want all three!

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DailyCount] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [date] => 2012-11-20
                    [customer_id] => 200
                    [env_id] => 100
                    [jobs] => 10
                )
       )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DailyCount] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [date] => 2012-11-21
                    [customer_id] => 200
                    [env_id] => 100
                    [jobs] => 10
                )

        )
)
```

I'm after all three rows for each date in my result - I need all three env_id job counts.

Any one help either how to do this in CakePHP or even how to get such a result in MySQL and I can figure out the cake way!

----------- HACK SOLUTION ------------

I can't answer my own question  so editing the question

Ok not the perfect solution but worked for me and was a fast solution:

```
$dailyCount = $this->Environment->DailyCount->find('all',
array(
'conditions' => array('DailyCount.customer_id' => $user['customer_id']),
'order' => array('DailyCount.date DESC'),
'limit' => $limit,
'recursive'=>-1));

$usage = array();
foreach($dailyCount as $dc){
    $usage[$dc['DailyCount']['date']][] = $dc;
}
```

Comment: If you need all 3 rows for each date, then why are you grouping? Using your example table, what resulting table are you looking for?

Comment: The result you are getting is right, you group by date where user id is something, so there should be one record

Comment: The result is good. The problem is in your understanding of cakephp resulting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/).  If you're grouping, that's probably your best bet.